# Accumulative mutable types with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Can we statically store types in TypeScript? Not sure how to exactly put it so here's the code:

```
type ScreenDefinition<Name extends string, Path extends string> = {
  name: Name;
  path: Path;
};

class Screen<Output = any> {
  _output!: Output;
  create<
    Name extends string,
    Path extends string,
    D extends ScreenDefinition<Name, Path>
  >(this: Screen<[Output, D]>, def: D) {
    this._output = [...this._output, def] as unknown as [Output, D];

    return this._output as unknown as [Output, D];
  }
}

const AdminRootScreen = new Screen();

AdminRootScreen.create({
  name: "My screen",
  path: "/my-screen",
  routePath: ["/my-screen"],
  accessPath: "test",
});

type Routes<RS> = RS extends Screen<any> ? RS["_output"] : never;

type AdminRoutes = Routes<typeof AdminRootScreen>; // { name: ... }
```

Is there a way (without codegen) to actually store every `.create` return type without having reference to newly created `this` of `Screen<[Output, D]>` type?

Comment: This is *very* confusing code and almost certainly doesn't mean what you want it to, even for example purposes. The `this` parameter isn't a "newly created `this`", it's a constraint, and so you're saying "when you call `create()`, it will be both a `Screen<Output>` *and* a `Screen<[Output, D]>`, which is very unlikely.  Oh and you're possibly writing types like `[[[any], D1], D2], D3]` but the *values* are `[d1, d2, d3]` which isn't the same type.  I think you might be looking for assertion functions but the example code is ‍♂️. Could you please [edit] to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: (continued) I mean, *maybe* you're looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJxQZN), but I could be way off.  Let me know.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz it's basically what I was looking for! Sorry this example is too specific, I was so eager to find a solution.

I assume in order to get the types, every `create` call have to be before accessing the `_output` type? Do you know if there's a way for it to be more or less "global"? So I'd call `create` in different modules and get the types in different ones - while still hoping to get the types from all the `create` calls

Comment: Assertion functions work via control flow analysis, so they all need to happen in a place where the compiler knows the order of operations. You can't have one in each file and have the compiler merge them.  If you want behavior like that with types alone you could use declaration merging, but it wouldn't have any runtime effect... so each time you merged something in you'd have to also call the function and nothing would warn you if you forgot to do the latter.  (more)

Comment: (continued) Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYQqQW) shows.  Not great.  So how should I write up an answer post here? Should I suggest my first approach, or say "this is impossible"?